# How to use NSWindowDidExposeNotification

Tags: cocoa, macos, nswindow

I am trying to update another windows when the one becomes visible. So I found the NSWindowDidExposeNotification and tried to work with it, so I wrote in my awakeFromNib:

```
// MyClass.m
- (void)awakeFromNib {
    NSNotificationCenter *nc = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
    [nc addObserver:self
           selector:@selector(mentionsWindowDidExpose:)
               name:NSWindowDidExposeNotification
             object:nil];
}
```

and implemented the method

```
// MyClass.h
- (void)mentionsWindowDidExpose:(id)sender;

// MyClass.m
- (void)mentionsWindowDidExpose:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"test");
}
```

But it never gets called which is odd. What do I do wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking, you would set up your controller as the window's [delegate](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/NSWindowDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSWindowDelegate) in order to receive these notifications, like so:

```
// MyClass.m
- (void)awakeFromNib {
    // note: this step can also be done in IB by dragging a connection
    // from the window's "delegate" property to your `MyClass` object
    [window setDelegate:self];
}

- (void)windowDidExpose:(NSNotification *)notification {
    NSLog(@"test");
}
```

Although, after reading [here](http://lists.apple.com/archives/cocoa-dev/2010/Mar/msg01468.html) and [here](http://lists.apple.com/archives/cocoa-dev/2002/Aug/msg01351.html), `windowDidExpose` may not be your best bet. I would recommend trying the [windowDidBecomeKey](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/NSWindowDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSWindowDelegate/windowDidBecomeKey:) delegate method instead. That one is posted whenever your window gains "focus" (starts responding to user input) which may be the right time to show your second window.

***Update:*** (in response to comments)

Apple's documentation (quoted below) indicates that `NSWindowDidExposeNotification` is only valid for [nonretained](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/WinPanel/Tasks/SettingWindowImageAttr.html) windows, which, according to the posts that I linked above, are quite uncommon.

> [**NSWindowDidExposeNotification**](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindow_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000013-BCICGDDI)
>
> Posted whenever a portion of a nonretained NSWindow object is exposed, whether by being ordered in front of other windows or by other windows being removed from in front of it.
>
> The notification object is the NSWindow object that has been exposed. The userInfo dictionary contains ... the rectangle that has been exposed.

On a higher level, `NSNotification` objects are simply packages of data that get passed around between Cocoa classes and `NSNotificationCenter` objects. `NSNotificationCenter` objects are controllers that manage these packages of data and send them out to observers as required. There is usually no need to trap notifications *directly*. You can simply use KVC/KVO or pre-defined delegates in your classes and Cocoa handles all of the dirty details behind the scenes.

See [Notification Programming Topics](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Notifications/Introduction/introNotifications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000043i) and [Key Value Coding Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/KeyValueCoding.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000107i) if you want to know more.

Comment: Ah yeah, that works nice, thanks I'll use that. But then I think I don't understand what NSWindowDidExposeNotification is fof.

Comment: My response was too long for a comment, so I posted it in my answer. I hope that's enough information to get you started! `:)`

Comment: Thanks, just one more question ;). What do they mean my a "nonretained NSWindow"? I't isn't where the retain count is just 0 or is it?

Comment: I added a link to my answer. Nonretained windows are defined as windows that do not have an off-screen buffer, so they must draw directly to the screen at all times. I suppose that explains the importance of the `WindowDidExpose` notification: it is used to indicate that a portion of the nonretained window has been uncovered (for instance if you moved another window on top of it, and then moved it away again). A buffered window would simply redraw the contents of the buffer to fill in the erased area, but the nonretained window has no buffer, so it *must* redraw it manually.

Comment: No worries. Good luck with the coding! `:)`